# Seeking datasets for training a Language Model on U.S. mortgage loan processes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp, dataset, data-mining

I'm in the process of training a Language Model (LLM) and require datasets that encompass various aspects of the U.S. mortgage loan process. The model's aim is to understand and simulate decision-making and advisory tasks within this domain.

Details:

Type of Data: I am looking for datasets with granular details on loan performance, approval rates, mortgage securities, and lending practices.
Intended Use: The data will be used to train a Language Model to grasp and generate information related to mortgage processes.
Required Specificity: Data should ideally span multiple years and include a broad spectrum of financial institutions.
What I've tried:

Searched the FHFA for data on market support activities and securities.
Looked at Fannie Mae's Loan Performance Data.
Investigated the National Mortgage Database for comprehensive mortgage market information.
Analyzed CFPB's data summaries for mortgage lending in 2021 and 2022.
Does anyone know where I might find additional datasets suitable for training a LLM? Any leads on datasets that are publicly available or purchasable would be incredibly helpful.